# I am reading timezone from rest api header, instead of giving local timezone it always give Etc/Utc

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, timezone, spring-webflux

I am trying to read timezone from api client(which is either mobile or postman), this is always returning zoneId as Etc/UTC, instead of actual timezone
But when I run the same code in my local machine I am getting proper timezone, please let me know how to read timezone from the request

```
private ZoneId getRequestTimeZone(ServerRequest request) {
        // Check if the "timezone" header is present in the request
        List<String> timezoneHeaders = request.headers().header("timezone");

        if (!timezoneHeaders.isEmpty()) {
            String timezoneHeaderValue = timezoneHeaders.get(0);
            try {
                return ZoneId.of(timezoneHeaderValue);
            } catch (DateTimeException e) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        "Invalid timezone: " + timezoneHeaderValue
                );
            }
        } else {
            // Default to a specific timezone if the header is not present
            return ZoneId.systemDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`timezone` is not a standard http header, so your code is going to the `else` branch and return the ZoneId of your machine.

There is no *standard* way of determining the client timezone from server side, unless the client explicitly puts this information in the request itself.

Comment: We have RequestContextUtils in spring
 RequestContextUtils.getTimeZone(request).

Do we have alternative for this in spring reactive?

Comment: You should add something to your client code, either you add something to http headers, or pass a query parameter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript on how to get it.